How to Remove Space between two embedded iframes/divs using WPBakery
https://wichitachec.com/
I can't figure out how to remove the gap/whitespace between the different divs/iframes
Hi, I've tried many different solutions and custom CSS and can't figure out how to remove the gap/whitespace between the different divs/iframe. I say both because I'm not sure which one is causing the gap. The videos are embedded from Canva. I tried negative margins in the rows but that messed up the view on Mobile.
Is there any css that could help me solve this?
Thank you in advance.
Here is the code for the Raw HTML block in WPBakery.
EDIT I was able to solve this due to someone's help, by removing the margin-top and margin-bottom attributes for each div style. These were automatically added by Canva, and I had tried setting them to '0' before, but completely removing them solved the issue for me.
<div style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 0; padding-top: 56.2225%; padding-bottom: 0; margin-top: 1.6em; margin-bottom: 0.9em; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 0px; will-change: transform;"><iframe style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; border: none; padding: 0; margin: 0;" src="https://www.canva.com/design/DAGTkfTf0FY/zfHjPdlrhoaS8A-3qKtCpA/view?embed">
</iframe></div>
<div style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 0; padding-top: 56.2225%; padding-bottom: 0; margin-top: 1.6em; margin-bottom: 0.9em; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 0px; will-change: transform;"><iframe style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; border: none; padding: 0; margin: 0;" src="https://www.canva.com/design/DAGTkg5Sp4k/81fuA8R8sIeW-Q7YGdUzWA/view?embed">
</iframe></div>
<div style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 0; padding-top: 56.2225%; padding-bottom: 0; margin-top: 1.6em; margin-bottom: 0.9em; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 0px; will-change: transform;"><iframe style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; border: none; padding: 0; margin: 0;" src="https://www.canva.com/design/DAGTkq_xg9s/PwDuAQfqn7Kk_xvQLs49Gg/view?embed">
</iframe></div>
<div style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 0; padding-top: 56.2225%; padding-bottom: 0; margin-top: 1.6em; margin-bottom: 0.9em; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 0px; will-change: transform;"><iframe style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; border: none; padding: 0; margin: 0;" src="https://www.canva.com/design/DAGTky-YuS0/yLTV0NX7SWC4xfI4C4Ulvw/view?embed">
</iframe></div>
<div style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 0; padding-top: 56.2225%; padding-bottom: 0; margin-top: 1.6em; margin-bottom: 0.9em; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 0px; will-change: transform;"><iframe style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; border: none; padding: 0; margin: 0;" src="https://www.canva.com/design/DAGTksqKjlI/5RMML-kwOeMZK0_Rpvc_oQ/view?embed">
</iframe></div>

